# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre .bashrc y .bash_profile?

Tags: linux, bash, macos

Quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia entre los archivos `.bashrc` y `.bash_profile` que suelen ir en la home de usuarios en sistemas opertativos Linux o Mac OS.

Si son lo mismo, ¿se puede tener solo uno de esos archivos?

En mi caso, tengo solamente en mi home el archivo .bash_profile y necesito ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
echo PATH=\"\$NPM_PACKAGES/bin\:\$PATH\" >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
```

¿Sería lo mismo si lo cambio a lo siguiente?

```
echo PATH=\"\$NPM_PACKAGES/bin\:\$PATH\" >> ${HOME}/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Lo habitual es utilizar .bashrc (siempre y cuando tu shell sea Bash que es lo más habitual). Lo mejor que puedes hacer en este caso es crear un nuevo .bashrc vacío (touch ~/.bashrc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- `.bash_profile` se ejecuta una sola vez, cuando inicias sesión.
- `.bashrc` se ejecuta cada vez que inicias el intérprete `bash`.

Al ejecutar el primer comando, si el archivo `.bashrc` no existe, se va a crear. Si ya existe, la línea se agrega al final.

Debido al propósito de la línea que quieres agregar, lo más recomendable es que sea en el `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 6):

Tradicionalmente, cuando haces login en un sistema Unix, el sistema abrirá un programa para ti. Ese programa es la shell, es decir, un programa diseñado para iniciar otros programas. Es un shell de línea de comandos: inicias otro programa tecleando su nombre. La shell por defecto, la shell Bourne, lee comandos de `~/.profile` cuando es invocada por la shell de login.

Bash es una shell de tipo Bourne. Lee comandos de `~/.bash_profile` cuando se invoca como la shell de login. Y si ese fichero no existe¹ intenta leer `~/.profile`.

Puedes invocar una shell directamente en cualquier momento. Por ejemplo, ejecutando un emulador de terminal dentro de un entorno GUI. Si la shell no es una shell de login, entonces no lee `~/.profile`. Cuando inicias bash como shell interactiva (es decir, no para ejecutar un script), lee `~/.bashrc` (excepto cuando se invocó como shell de login, en cuyo caso solo lee `~/.bash_profile` o `~/.profile`).

Por tanto:

- `~/.profile` es el fichero donde guardar las cosas que aplican a toda la sesión, como los programas que quieres iniciar cuando haces log in (pero no programas gráficos, pues van en otro fichero distinto) y definiciones de variables de entorno.
- `~/.bashrc` es el fichero donde guardar las cosas que aplican solamente a bash en sí, como los alias y las definiciones de funciones, así como configuraciones del prompt. (También podrías poner key bindings aquí, pero en bash normalmente se ponen en `~/.inputrc`).
- `~/.bash_profile` puede usarse en lugar de `~/.profile`, pero solamente lo lee bash y no las otras shells. (Esto es importante tenerlo en cuenta si quieres que tus ficheros de inicialización funcionen en distintas máquinas y bash no es la shell de login de todas ellas) Este es el lugar lógico para incluir `~/.bashrc` si la shell es interactiva. Por ello recomiendo poner lo siguiente en `~/.bash_profile`:

  ```
  if [ -r ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
  case "$-" in *i*) if [ -r ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi;; esac
  ```

En sistemas UNIX modernos existe una complicación añadida relacionada con `~/.profile`. Si haces log in en un entorno gráfico (esto es, si el programa donde escribes tu contraseña está corriendo en modo gráfico) no recibes automáticamente una shell de login que lee `~/.profile`. Dependiendo en el programa gráfico de login, en el gestor de ventanas o el entorno de escritorio que corra después y en cómo configura estos programas tu distribución, tu `~/.profile` puede que se lea, pero puede que no. Si no se lee, normalmente hay otro lugar donde definir variables de entorno y programas a lanzar cuando haces log in, pero lamentablemente ese lugar no tiene una localización estándar.

Nótese que puede que leas aquí y allí recomendaciones de poner la definición de variables de entorno en `~/.bashrc` o lanzar shells de login en terminales. Ambas son malas ideas. El problema más común de estas ideas es que tus variables de entorno solo serán definidas en los programas lanzados desde la terminal, pero no en los que se inicien directamente con un icono, a través del menú o con algún atajo de teclado.

¹  <sub>Si `.bash_profile` no existe, bash también intenta `.bash_login` antes de intentar con `.profile`. Siéntete libre de olvidar que existe.</sub>

> <sub>Respuesta traducida de [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/a/183980/204979), publicada por Gilles en Super User.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

~/.bashrc es el lugar para poner cosas que sólo se aplica a bash en sí, como alias y definiciones de función, shell opciones, y del sistema de configuración. (También se puede poner clave de los enlaces que hay, pero para bash que normalmente van en ~/.inputrc.)

~/.bash_profile puede ser utilizado en lugar de ~/.profile, pero es leído por bash, no por cualquier otro shell. (Esto es más preocupante si desea que los archivos de inicialización para trabajar en múltiples máquinas y su shell de inicio de sesión no es bash en todos ellos.) Este es un lugar lógico para incluir ~/.bashrc si es el shell interactivo. Recomiendo el siguiente contenido en ~/.bash_profile: